Show that $f(x) = \frac x{1 + |x|}$ is one-one where $f: \mathbb R\to (-1, 1)$

Show that $f(x) = \frac x{1 + |x|}$ is one-one where $f: \mathbb R\to (-1, 1)$.

I have solved it for $x_1, x_2 > 0$ and for $x_1, x_2 < 0$. I am facing problem with $x_1 > 0$ and $x_2 < 0$. I am getting a positive value = negative value, kind of solution, which clearly is not possible. But my teacher tells me that it is one-one. Can you point out what I am doing wrong here?

What have you solved for $x_1, x_2 > 0$  and $x_1, x_2 < 0$?

i have showed that for $f(x1) = f(x2)$, $x1 = x2$

Why can't you show the same when $x_1>0$ and $x_2 < 0$ ?

because, then I get $x1 - x2 = 2x1x2$. and since $x1 - x2 > 0$, it is not possible.

You may type x_1 for subscript $x_1$. And as you said, $x_1-x_2=2x_1x_2$ is absurd. How come we have such absurd consequence? Precisely because we assumed the existence of $x_1>0>x_2$ s.t. $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Therefore that $x_1-x_2=2x_1x_2$ is absurd implies the existence of such $x_1,x_2$ is impossible.

You want to prove that
\begin{equation}
f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Longrightarrow x_1 = x_2
\end{equation}
When $x_1 <0$ and $x_2>0$, the relation $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ is impossible because as you said, $f(x_1)<0$ and $f(x_2)>0$. Now if $P$ and $Q$ are two propositions and $P$ is impossible, then $P\Rightarrow Q$ is true. So when $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ is impossible, it is true that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1=x_2$.

Obviously the function $f$ is odd and continuous on $\mathbb R$.
When $x>0$, we have
$$f'(x)=\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)'=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}>0,$$
this implies $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$. Due to $f$ is odd and continuous,
we know $f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$.
So $f:\mathbb R\to (-1,1)$ is bijection.
